# Angular MSAL Guard: RenewIdToken has been called

Tags: angular, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

I am using Angular 9 and have a dotnet core web api, both protected using Azure B2C.

Everything is working fine, except the MsalGuard seems to request a new Id token after each route activation? This is what the logger is outputting after each navigation.

```
MSAL Logging:  Mon, 14 Sep 2020 10:40:58 GMT:fcbfd80b-29e4-4ec6-b013-e871a247a091-1.4.0-Info RenewIdToken has been called
main.js:317 MSAL Logging:  Mon, 14 Sep 2020 10:41:00 GMT:fcbfd80b-29e4-4ec6-b013-e871a247a091-1.4.0-Info ProcessCallBack has been called. Processing callback from redirect response
main.js:317 MSAL Logging:  Mon, 14 Sep 2020 10:41:00 GMT:fcbfd80b-29e4-4ec6-b013-e871a247a091-1.4.0-Info State status: true; Request type: LOGIN
main.js:317 MSAL Logging:  Mon, 14 Sep 2020 10:41:00 GMT:fcbfd80b-29e4-4ec6-b013-e871a247a091-1.4.0-Info State is right
main.js:317 MSAL Logging:  Mon, 14 Sep 2020 10:41:00 GMT:fcbfd80b-29e4-4ec6-b013-e871a247a091-1.4.0-Info Fragment has idToken
main.js:317 MSAL Logging:  Mon, 14 Sep 2020 10:41:00 GMT:fcbfd80b-29e4-4ec6-b013-e871a247a091-1.4.0-Info unprotectedResources is deprecated and ignored. msalAngularConfig.protectedResourceMap now supports glob patterns
main.js:317 MSAL Logging:  Mon, 14 Sep 2020 10:41:09 GMT:fcbfd80b-29e4-4ec6-b013-e871a247a091-1.4.0-Info unprotectedResources is deprecated and ignored. msalAngularConfig.protectedResourceMap now supports glob patterns
```

My config file

```
export const b2cPolicies = {
  names: {
    signUpSignIn: 'domain',
    resetPassword: 'b2c_1_reset',
    editProfile: 'b2c_1_edit_profile',
  },
  authorities: {
    signUpSignIn: {
      authority: 'https://domain.b2clogin.com/domain.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_signup',
    },
    resetPassword: {
      authority: 'https://domain.b2clogin.com/domain.onmicrosoft.com/b2c_1_reset',
    },
    editProfile: {
      authority: 'https://domain.b2clogin.com/domain.onmicrosoft.com/b2c_1_edit_profile',
    },
  },
};

export const apiConfig: { b2cScopes: string[]; webApi: string } = {
  b2cScopes: ['https://domain.onmicrosoft.com/api/user_access'],
  webApi: 'https://localhost:44363/',
};

export const msalConfig: Configuration = {
  auth: {
    clientId: '0000...',
    authority: b2cPolicies.authorities.signUpSignIn.authority,
    redirectUri: 'http://localhost:4201/',
    postLogoutRedirectUri: 'http://localhost:4201/',
    navigateToLoginRequestUrl: true,
    validateAuthority: false,
  },
  cache: {
    cacheLocation: 'localStorage',
    storeAuthStateInCookie: isIE, // Set this to "true" to save cache in cookies to address trusted zones limitations in IE
  },
};

export const loginRequest: { scopes: string[] } = {
  scopes: ['openid', 'profile'],
};

export const tokenRequest: { scopes: string[] } = {
  scopes: apiConfig.b2cScopes, // i.e. [https://fabrikamb2c.onmicrosoft.com/helloapi/demo.read]
};

export const protectedResourceMap: [string, string[]][] = [
  [apiConfig.webApi, apiConfig.b2cScopes], // i.e. [https://fabrikamb2chello.azurewebsites.net/hello, ['https://fabrikamb2c.onmicrosoft.com/helloapi/demo.read']]
];

export const msalAngularConfig: MsalAngularConfiguration = {
  popUp: true,
  consentScopes: [...loginRequest.scopes, ...tokenRequest.scopes],
  unprotectedResources: [], // API calls to these coordinates will NOT activate MSALGuard
  protectedResourceMap, // API calls to these coordinates will activate MSALGuard
  extraQueryParameters: {},
};
```

Essentially each route that is protected using the msal guard takes about 2 seconds to load because it's getting a new token each time? I can't figure out why this would happen?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Did you update dependencies recently? This just happened to me today when I updated to msal: 1.4.0 & @azure/msal-angular: 1.1.1. I reverted back to msal: 1.3.4 and don't see the problem.

Comment: Thanks for this. This fix the issue in my end.  But instead of downgrading it to 1.3.4, I upgraded it to 1.4.4 and it fixed the issue with the token.